# Discogs API => How to retrieve genre?

Tags: python, csv, python-requests, api-key, discogs-api

I've crawled a tracklist of 36.000 songs, which have been played on the Danish national radio station P3. I want to do some statistics on how frequently each of the genres have been played within this period, so I figured the discogs API might help labeling each track with genre. However, the documentation for the API doesent seem to include an example for querying the genre of a particular song.

I have a CSV-file with with 3 columns: Artist, Title & Test(Test where i want the API to label each song with the genre).

Here's a sample of the script i've built so far:

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import requests
import discogs_client
d = discogs_client.Client('ExampleApplication/0.1')
d.set_consumer_key('key-here', 'secret-here')

input = pd.read_csv('Desktop/TEST.csv', encoding='utf-8',error_bad_lines=False)

df = input[['Artist', 'Title', 'Test']]
df.columns = ['Artist', 'Title','Test']

for i in range(0, len(list(df.Artist))):
x = df.Artist[i]
g = d.artist(x)
df.Test[i] = str(g)

df.to_csv('Desktop/TEST2.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

This script has been working with a dummy file with 3 records in it so far, for mapping the artist of a given ID#. But as soon as the file gets larger(ex. 2000), it returns a HTTPerror when it cannot find the artist.

I have some questions regarding this approach:

1) Would you recommend using the search query function in the API for retrieving a variable as 'Genre'. Or do you think it is possible to retrieve Genre with a 'd.' function from the API?

2) Will I need to aquire an API-key? I have succesfully mapped the 3 records without an API-key so far. Looks like the key is free though.

Here's the guide I have been following:
https://github.com/discogs/discogs_client

And here's the documentation for the API:
https://www.discogs.com/developers/#page:home,header:home-quickstart

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to re-read the discogs_client examples, i am not an expert myself, but a newbie trying to use this API.

AFAIK, g = d.artist(x) fails because x must be a integer not a string.

So you must first do a search, then get the artist id, then d.artist(artist_id)

Sorry for no providing an example, i am python newbie right now ;)

Also have you checked acoustid for

Comment: In Stack Overflow you should be as helpful as possible. When posting an answer try to write an example of code if you can or show some research results. Check http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer to learn more. Welcome to SO.

Comment: bleuge >> so I need the artist ID before i can query data about the artist / title? The documentation is kinda limited.. Not much explanation of the functions IMO

Answer (score 0):

It's a probably a rate limit.
Read the status code of your response, you should find an 429 Too Many Requests

Unfortunately, if that's the case, the only solution is to add a sleep in your code to make one request per second.

Checkout the api doc: 
http://www.discogs.com/developers/#page:home,header:home-rate-limiting

Comment: I get a:

HTTPError: 404: Artist not found.

I've read that their limit on image query's are 300 a minute, so I tried adding that to my python code. However, I keep getting 404's.

Comment: Seems that the 404's might be the thing thats holding the query's back. In the rate-limiting section of the api doc, it says: "Currently, the only rate-limited resource is the image type, but your application should be intelligent enough to know if we start rate-limiting others."

Answer (score 0):

I found this guide:

```
https://github.com/neutralino1/discogs_client.
```

Access the api with your key and try something like:

```
d = discogs_client.Client('something.py', user_token=auth_token)
release = d.release(774004)
genre = release.genres
```

If you found a better solution please share.